# Replacing #N/A with If OR statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that mostly contains numbers, but occasionally blank cells and errors(`#N/A`).
I want to create another dataset in which the blanks and `#N/A`s are replaced by a default (`100`).

```
=if(not(isnumber(c10)),100,c10)
```

seems to work, but, if I also want to replace values less than 100, with 100, using `If(Or(`

```
=if(or(c10<100,not(isnumber(c10))),100,c10)
```

This returns `#N/A`

Comment: you should use IFERROR

Answer (score 1):

use

```
=IFNA(IF(OR(A1<100,A1=""),100,A1),100)
```

or

```
=IFS(ISNA(A1),100,A1="",100,A1<100,100,TRUE,A1)
```

This has the features

- `#N/A` is converted to `100` but other errors are left intact
- an empty string returns `100`
- Other text is left intact

[image]

The alternative

```
=IFERROR(IF(--A1<100,100,A1),100)
```

would convert *all* errors to `100`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Excel OR and AND does not have short circuit, so flipping the conditions like

```
=if(or(not(isnumber(c10)),c10<100),100,c10)
```

doesn't work... you have to use a dozen of IF

```
=if(isnumber(c10), if(c10<100, 100, c10), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98CGj3baDKvQZgat_?e=vFrjI5) refer:

Allow for evaluation of OR to an error re: `OR(iserror(a3),a3="",a3<100)` as follows:

```
=IF(IFERROR(OR(ISERROR(A3),A3="",A3<100),1),$J$1,A3)
```

*customise 'default' value (J1) as req.*

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Personally prefer some of other solns offered here...

Comment: FWIW, the `ISERROR(A3)` is redundant.  (If A3 is an error, both A3="" and A3<100 return errors, so the OR also returns an error, which is then caught by the IFERROR).  Formula may be reduced to `=IF(IFERROR(OR(A3="",A3<100),1),$J$1,A3)`

Comment: True - fyi - not clear OP wishes to exclude all types of errors (isna will only pick out specific types - otherwise iserror/iferror may be required in yours)

Comment: Yep, OP is unclear on several edge cases.  (does "blanks" mean empty cells, empty strings, or both; what to do with: other errors; text; dates).  Without input from the OP we can only guess.

Comment: very true - I quite like the isna approach - parsimonious in way; my only slight 'gripe' with it is it relates to v. specific type of 'user-induced' errors - e.g. typically in regards to incorrect usage of function or function returning an error (Microsoft cites vlookup or derivative of this as most common cause).  Will wait to see what OP had in mind :)

Comment: Thank you, new to this OP = original poster?